# ImportError: No module named 'bottle' in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I installed bottle on Python 3.4 with pip install. In the terminal, when I do:

```
$ python3.4
>>>import bottle # shows no import error
>>>
```

but when I do it in PyCharm, it says:

> import bottle ImportError: No module named 'bottle'

Answer (score 134, accepted):

in your PyCharm project:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to open the settings
- on the left column, select *Project Interpreter*
- on the top right there is a list of python binaries found on your system, pick the right one
- eventually click the `+` button to install additional python modules
- validate

[image]

Comment: your welcome, also note a useful trick in the Settings panel, click the gear button above the `+` button and pick "Create VirtualEnv" to create a new environment in which the modules you will install later on won't mess up your python installation system-wide. This is also useful is you want to test different versions of a same module.

Comment: "Project Interpreter" is now under Settings > Project: [your project] > Project Interpreter. Or alternatively just use the search feature with Ctrl + Shift + A.

Comment: How can I do this for a locally developed module?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson, go to `Project structure` in the menu and add the folder containing that module sources to the sources

Answer (score 80):

In some cases no "No module ..." can appear even on local files. In such cases you just need to mark appropriate directories as "source directories":

[image: Mark as source lib directory]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The settings are changed for PyCharm 5+.

- Go to File > Default Settings
- In left sidebar, click Default Project > Project Interpreter
- At bottom of window, click + to install or - to uninstall.
- If we click +, a new window opens where we can decrease the results by entering the package name/keyword.
- Install the package.
- Go to File > Invalidate caches/restart and click Invalidate and Restart to apply changes and restart PyCharm.

Settings:

[image: Settings]

Install package:

[image: Install package]

Comment: If I follow your steps until "Install the package" it seems to be that pycharm isn't able to install the package because after 10 minutes it is still not installed. That doesn't seem to be normal.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. For me, it was the incorrect interpreter, which was by default using the virtual interpreter from the project.

So, make sure you select the correct one, as the pip install will install the package to the system Python interpreter.

[image: IDE settings]

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm 2019.3, my solution is below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the above worked, and curiously even within one file some imports worked, some didn't:

```py
from folder1.folder2.folder3.my_python_file import this_function  # worked
from folder1.folder2.folder3.my_python_file import that_function  # didn't work
```

Follow the above advice, but if it doesn't fix it additionally, (in PyCharm) click `File` >> `Repair IDE` and confirm all the 6 steps one after another.

Answer (score 1):

I had virtual env site package problem and this solved it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you are able to import the module when using the CLI interpreter  but not in PyCharm, make sure your project interpreter in PyCharm is set to an actual interpreter (eg. /usr/bin/python2.7) and not venv (~/PycharmProject/venv/...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried all fixes like installing from the project interpreter and installing from python console, nothing worked. What worked was just going to the project folder from the terminal and installing it from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame that I have to revisit this thread every once in a while to fix the same `ModuleNotFound` exception over and over again since 2016... Sometimes I have a new package and PyCharm cannot locate it, sometimes we upgrade to a newer Python version and PyCharm just throws it at me again, that's quite annoying.

In general, first you would want to check if the Python interpreter is the correct one, then try to mark the directory as source root and add it to the `PYTHONPATH`, remove any `__pycache__` folders, invalidate cache and restart the IDE, wait for it to reindex your files or update the skeletons. Your last resort is to uninstall the package and reinstall it from the interpreter.

Recently I had this happened to me again and the way I solved it is quite interesting. I can import the module from PyCharm's built-in terminal but not in any script, and of course none of the solutions above worked. So, in case you've tried everything else with no luck, and the source root or interpreter are all correct, here's the solution you might want to try out:

- Right click on your starting script, select "Edit Run Configuration..."
- Under the "Configuration" tab, check the box "Run with Python Console"
- Right click again to run your script, the `import` should succeed but you still cannot run it from the debugger
- Go back to the "Configuration" tab, uncheck the box you previously checked
- Now try running the script from the debugger, PyCharm should be able to find your modules

I have no idea why checking and then unchecking the box would magically fix the issue, but it just works.

Comment: The above methods are correct and if something goes wrong there isn't a "magic trick" of ticking/unticking a box. The explanation is in how the [run/ debug configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html) are written by the IDE together with how your [project wide configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-up-your-project.html) are set. Your description corresponds to generating a new default run configuration using the wrong interpreter.

Comment: The solution to your case is setting the right [project interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#view_list) and then being careful about [how you launch a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965627/how-to-get-back-debug-console-in-pycharm) so the default run configuration is created correctly.

Comment: @bad_coder Thanks for sharing the links and I can see how they work under the hood now, but my issue is not like what you just described. In my case, the project interpreter is already correct in the first place (I only have one interpreter), it's pointing to the same location that `which python` returns in the built-in terminal, but the import still fails. Then I tick the box to run with Python console, which generates a new default run configuration using exactly the same interpreter, and now import succeeds. After that I untick the box without changing anything else, import also succeeds.

Comment: @bad_coder Throughout there's only one interpreter "Python 3.7.5.7" in my configuration, and it's the correct one. I added it right after removing my old "Python 3.7.5.6" interpreter, so I don't have two interpreters existing at the same time. It seems that when I change the old interpreter to a new one, PyCharm just fails to update the `xml` file in `.idea` folder as I can tell the last modified time of that file does not change. However when I tick that box, this time it generates a new configuration file and the file does get updated after I untick it.

Comment: @bad_coder I might have run into a file permission issue where PyCharm doesn't have the permission to write to or invalidate the old configuration file. I have no idea about the details but thanks to your comment now I know exactly where to look at next time.

Comment: When you say: *"It seems that when I change the old interpreter to a new one, PyCharm just fails to update"* PyCharm isn't supposed to update old run configurations, they retain the same interpreter they were created with unless you update it manually. When you say: *"`which python` returns in the built-in terminal, but the import still fails"* the interpreter your terminal starts with is taken from a [somewhat unexpected source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69099819) depending not on how many interpreters you have but how many projects are opened in that window.

Comment: I see, so it all boils down to "update the configuration manually" - that's what I was trying to do but cannot figure out how. I was updating my interpreter in `Settings->Project Interpreter` and `Edit Run Configuration` and invalidating the cache and removing all `__pycache__` folders, but even then after restarting PyCharm my project still seems to be using the old configuration (so the import fails), until I tick/untick that magic box.....

Comment: If that's the case it would be a separate bug or an error in your overall setup. The first step is checking the configuration files actually get written to file when you change something using the GUI.

Comment: Yep I would manually check and inspect the configuration files if the issue ever happens again. That's much more reliable than blindly tweaking things in the UI.