# PyCharm: ImportError no module named

Tags: python, pycharm, pydicom

I have a problem with a package 'pydicom' on macos. In pycharm I get an error [ImportError: No module named dicom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmeXN.png)

My code runs from the terminal without any problem (>> python abc.py or >> python2.7 abc.py). I checked the project interpreter, [as you can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmeXN.png)

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm) is does not help.

**EDIT**
I created a new project with the same code and now everything works. 
I believe the only thing I changed in the old project was 'Project interpreter'. Interesting.

Comment: is the dicom library installed? you might need to install it first by doing pip install pydicom. refer http://pydicom.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#installing

Comment: Yes, I used 'sudo easy_install pydicom' in terminal. When I type it again I get: 
'pydicom 0.9.9 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pydicom-0.9.9-py2.7.egg'

Comment: See this page for how to install libraries in your PyCharm environment https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html You can also add requirements files as shown here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/creating-requirement-files.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'bottle' - PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm)