# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CairoSVG'

Tags: python, pycharm

I have this code:

```
import CairoSVG
```

but I get this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" D:/PyCharmProjects/Exyz/Bla.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharmProjects/xyz/Bla.py", line 1, in <module>
    import CairoSVG
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CairoSVG'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm) and the package CairoSVG is definitely installed. I also did:

```
Go to File > Invalidate caches/restart and click Invalidate and Restart to apply changes and restart PyCharm.
```

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
import cairosvg
```

instead of

```
import CairoSVG
```

should fix your problem.

Source : http://cairosvg.org/

Comment: python is really picky about module case