# Error importing psutil in PyCharm Google App Engine Project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm, psutil

I have recently run into an import error with psutils in the types.py called from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 on a GAE standard project inside Pycharm. I messed around for a day trying to find away around it, but no go. psutil imports in python run from the terminal and the console and from a vanilla python project but not from a GAE project. To double up on this I made a basic test of the two as seen below: Both using the same virtualenv...

---

Standard Vanilla Python Project:

main.py contains

```
import psutil

def x():
    print "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x()
```

Google App Engine Project -
main.py contains

```
import webapp2
import psutil

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

The import in the vanilla python project works fine, but the import in the GAE app returns the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/chez 1/google-app-engine-projects/untitled/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import psutil
ImportError: No module named psutil
```

Has anyone had similar problems and found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely having the `psutil` package installed on your local system (thus working in terminal/console), but not vendored into your app (i.e installed in your app's `lib` dir) as **required** for standard env apps (the SDK emulates the real GAE, for which whatever is installed into your local python installation means nothing). From [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library):

> 1. Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as `lib/`.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ```
> 2. Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous
>      step. For example:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>    ```

So just vendor into your app the `psutil` package.

Comment: I've tried that and I get the following error:
 
ImportError: No module named psutil._psutil_osx

Comment: Hm, that package is likely to violate the GAE sandbox restrictions, it *might* have something to do with that: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_The_sandbox

Comment: Well, if it does why use it in a GAE package?

Comment: Well, pub/sub wasn't exactly designed for GAE, plus standard and flex GAE are some significantly different beasts. Hm, flex has its own [pub/sub doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages), the standard env doesn't. I admit, I'm speculating.

Comment: In [cloud-pubsub-samples-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-python/tree/master/appengine-push) I see they have only `google-api-python-client` in requirements.txt, they don't specifically import `psutils`.

Comment: So what did you end up doing finally @Chez, cause i have run into exactly same situation

Comment: Anuj, you have a few choices. Use the standard google client api for access to use pub/sub or use some other push notification system. You can also write a method on the Google cloud in say node.js that you can call which in turn calls the pub/sub routine.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this and similar '*No module named ...*' errors have been caused by an incorrectly defined python interpreter.  See the answers at: [ImportError: No module named 'bottle' - PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm)