# Selenium cannot be found when running the python script from CommandLine

Tags: python, selenium, cmd, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

I'm using python to write a selenium script. Selenium is already installed and imported in my script and it is all fine when I run the script on Pycharm IDE, no issues or error.

But when I tried using cmd to run my script, it showed a error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You might find something helpful here. Look at the comments on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439686/running-py-script-from-cmd-fails-cant-find-module-selenium)

If you need a library in a specific environment you need to install it in that environment. Pycharm likely maintains its own environments. Use the environment it created (look in your settings for "interpreter" and use that path when running Python) or install the library into the environment you're using. (sys is included in the standard library, so it's not a good point of comparison.)

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "use that path when running Python"?

Comment: Maybe pycharm is running on different environment and that env have selenium installed. Did you check that?

Comment: the issue is solved, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This error message executing the python script from *commandline*...

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

...indicates that the *Selenium* library wasn't installed in your system disk but was installed with *PyCharm's* virtual environment, i.e. within:

```
C:\Users\user_name\PycharmProjects\project_name\venv
```

which your system isn't aware.

### Solution

To execute the python script from *CLI* you need to install the *Selenium* library within your system disk using either of the following commands:

- From commandline using *pip* (install):

  ```
  $pip install selenium
  ```
- From commandline using *pip3* (install or upgrade):

  ```
  $pip3 install -U selenium
  ```

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to install the library from cmd. Now it can be run on cmd finally, thanks for your help!

Comment: @NKFAI Glad to be able to help you.