# How to get back Debug Console in PyCharm?

Tags: python, windows, debugging, pycharm, console

How can one restore the Debug Console within PyCharm if it is not showing? I've found it comes back if I restart debugging but outside of this, is there any other way?

I've been reading the docs and searching quite a bit for the answer but so far have not found a way.

The animated image below shows the debug console open in the bottom part of the screen, and also later on in the same image it appears closed. If this is closed, is there a way to get it back without starting a new debug run?

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the question, but the debugger tool window has two tabs - "Console" and "Debugger", did you try clicking on the "Console" one to open the console?

Comment: @PavelKarateev The "console" or some portion of it would have to be visible for clicking to be possible. Its invisible is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice there are two different ways to use and launch the console.

A. One is using <kbd>Alt + Shift + E</kbd> which launches the console by calling `C:\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py` without it being associated to any file or project. This way has its own Tool Window in `View` `>` `Tool Windows` `>` `Python Console`.

B. The other way is running a debug configuration by pressing <kbd>Shift + F9</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt + Shift + F9</kbd>), this launches the debugger process at `C:\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py` and does associate it with the script of your run configurations. This also uses a separate Tool Window `View` `>` `Tool Windows` `>` `Debug` (<kbd>Alt + 5</kbd>).

> If this is closed, is there a way to get it back without starting a new debug run?

Yes by choosing "Run with Python Console" in the Run/Configurations. After the debugger finishes the Console in the "Debugger Pane" persists.

> And it can be useful to have it on because the Console can contain logs from the last completed run

I hadn't noticed this, but the command history is actually shared between the 2 console windows. So if you click the "Browse Query History" you have it available from one window to the other.

Comment: In a lot of instances, the debugger pane is actually available even absent an active debug session. And it can be useful to have it on because the Console can contain logs from the last completed run. So, it does not seem to make sense to me that you cannot call up the Debug console if you are not in active debugging.

Comment: @paolov I revised my answer, it does work. There are ["a few posts"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+attach+debugger) with use cases for this. Personally I haven't had a need to use the console like this before.