# python module not found after executing shell script even though the module is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

```
pip3 list
Package             Version
------------------- ------------
apipkg              1.5
apparmor            3.0.3
appdirs             1.4.4
asn1crypto          1.4.0
brotlipy            0.7.0
certifi             2021.5.30
cffi                1.14.6
chardet             4.0.0
cmdln               2.0.0
configobj           5.0.6
createrepo-c        0.17.3
cryptography        3.3.2
cssselect           1.1.0
cupshelpers         1.0
cycler              0.10.0
decorator           5.0.9
idna                3.2
iniconfig           0.0.0
isc                 2.0
joblib              1.0.1
kiwisolver          1.3.1
LibAppArmor         3.0.3
lxml                4.6.3
matplotlib          3.4.3
mysqlclient         2.0.3
nftables            0.1
notify2             0.3.1
numpy               1.21.1
opi                 2.1.1
ordered-set         3.1.1
packaging           20.9
pandas              1.3.1
Pillow              8.3.1
pip                 20.2.4
ply                 3.11
psutil              5.8.0
py                  1.10.0
pyasn1              0.4.8
pycairo             1.20.1
pycparser           2.20
pycups              2.0.1
pycurl              7.43.0.6
PyGObject           3.40.1
pyOpenSSL           20.0.1
pyparsing           2.4.7
pysmbc              1.0.23
PySocks             1.7.1
python-dateutil     2.8.2
python-linux-procfs 0.6
pytz                2021.1
pyudev              0.22.0
requests            2.25.1
rpm                 4.16.1.3
scikit-learn        0.24.2
scipy               1.7.1
setuptools          57.4.0
six                 1.16.0
sklearn             0.0
slip                0.6.5
slip.dbus           0.6.5
termcolor           1.1.0
threadpoolctl       2.2.0
torch               1.9.0+cu111
torchaudio          0.9.0
torchvision         0.10.0+cu111
tqdm                4.62.1
typing-extensions   3.10.0.0
urllib3             1.26.6
```

Above shows my installed modules, but when i go into the project folder, and run the shell script, I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
```

Even though in the list above it clearly shows that torch is installed.

Please help. My `$PATH` is `/usr/bin/python:/home/anthony/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/snap/bin`

and my printenv PYTHONPATH is `:/usr/bin/python`

Let me know if you need any other print outs, I've tried everything, and nothing seems to be working. I am working mainly in pycharm.

Comment: Please, update with the complete traceback. Are you sure you're not running your script using Python 2?

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you sure you're using the same interpreter? Many IDEs (including PyCharm) create a virtual env for each project by default.

Comment: Is this helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm

Comment: Is `torch` listed under Setting > Project > Python Interpreter in PyCharm? If not, you only installed `torch` for the system interpreter. You didn't install it for the interpreter being used by PyCharm. Virtual environments don't inherit system packages by default.

Comment: @Berriel I could but how do i change that?

Comment: @Brian yes it listed. Even when I use the pycharm terminal it still says torch is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that `pip3` is pointing to a different python instance.

Imagine you had `python`, `python3`, `python3.6` and `python3.8` all installed on your system. Which one would `pip3` install packages for? (who knows?)

It is almost always safer to do `python3.8 -m pip list/install` since you can be sure that `python3.8 somefile.py` will be using the same files you just saw. (even better, do `python3.8 -m venv /path/to/some/virtualenv` and then make sure that is activated, then you can be sure `pip` points to the same `python`)

Comment: when i ran `python3.8 -m pip list' in showed the same list above. I added my projects venv to using your line above, do I have to reinstall the modules? Is there a way to remove all the other modules so i don't have duplicates everywhere?

Comment: if you did `python3.8 -m pip list` ... did you use `python3.8` to run your script?

Comment: The best practice is to duplicate the dependencies, keep your projects separate. Pip will cache downloaded files and be smart about it, but your life will be better if you just go along with it.