# Pycharm doesn't recognise installed module even though I can see it in pip freeze

Tags: python, import, pip, pycharm, python-venv

I'm trying to use the bar_chart_race module from a git respository. The problem is when I do in the terminal

```
 pip install git+https://github.com/programiz/bar_chart_race.git@master
```

everything seems to work fine and when I try `pip freeze` the module in pycharm is there. However whenever I try to import the module I get an error saying `No module named 'bar_chart_race'`

Comment: Sounds like you have two versions of python installed on your computer. The bar chart package is installed for one of them, but not the other. Update your pycharm configuration to use the correct python version.

Answer (score 0):

You Have  to select the appropriate interpreter in your configuration.

Please check below :
[ImportError: No module named 'bottle' - PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069254/importerror-no-module-named-bottle-pycharm)